# How test Azure storage file service and Google storage on local?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, google-cloud-storage, azure-storage

I am making a file repository that allows a website / program to save files to different systems (e.g. local, Azure File, Azure Blob, Google Storage) but I am having problems with making integration tests.

I was able to make integration tests for the Local File System, Azure Blob (Through the use of azure storage emulator) but could not find the way to test Azure File, Google Storage on the local host without the need to go though Google Cloud or Azure. Is there a way to make integration tests for them, that will work on local host?

I am using C#, Google Cloud Storage SDK, Azure Storage SDK.

Comment: For Azure Blobs, can you please confirm that you're targeting storage emulator for integration testing?

Comment: With Azure Blobs I am targeting storage emulator for integration testing.  The storage emulator work well but does not support Azure File Service. I do not have a  Azure or Google cloud account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File service and SMB protocol service endpoints are not currently supported in the Azure storage emulator.

[Reference: Differences between the storage emulator and Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage)

> Is there a way to be able to make integration tests for them, that will work on local host?

I haven't found any way to test Azure File Storage on local host.

To test Azure storage file service, you could start a one-month free trial of Azure subscription. You will receive $200 of Azure credits with the Free Trial.  Consume no more than $200 in a month, you can store 800 GB of data in Azure Storage Service. It is enough to test your application.

[Azure Free Trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/)